# IEnumerable To Observable with interval

Tags: c#, system.reactive

To generate a "measure" every 5 sec I'm doing something like :

```
var Events = Observable.
    Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).
    Select(i => factory.GenerateRandomMeasure())
```

I would like to do the same but based on an existing Measure collection.
I assume I have to do something like :

```
var Events = existingList.ToObservable();
```

But is It possible to do add an interval notion in order to get each list item with a interval? (one item every 5 sec for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either of these which work just fine:

(1)

```
var Events =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Zip(existingList, (i, x) => x)
        .Select(i => factory.GenerateRandomMeasure());
```

(2)

```
var Events2 =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            x => x < existingList.Count,
            x => x + 1,
            x => existingList[x],
            x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .Select(i => factory.GenerateRandomMeasure());
```

The first is probably more sensible and easier to write. The second is very much worth learning if you don't know it already as `.Generate` is very powerful and can be used in a lot of places.

Comment: I choose the second solution! It is perfect. Maybe it was not clear but I'm not using anymore the factory in this case. My usage is from the factory with random measure OR from existing list. But both with an interval.